# What's the text in "Mystische Jagd" by Martin Schongauer?

Tags: painting

I'm currently trying to figure out what's written on the banners in the right panel of the two piece painting "Mystische Jagd" by [Martin Schongauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Schongauer).

I'm pretty sure it's written in Latin but I can't decipher all the letters and I didn't learn Latin in school either. [Here](https://www.akg-images.co.uk/archive/La-chasse-mystique-2UMDHUCAURE.html) you can find the image:

[image]

I think the upper banner reads *urna auria* which apparently means *golden pot*. However what's on the lower one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

> 6. The golden urn (URNA AURIA).
>    This urn seems to be full of golden apples. `Urna aurea beata est Maria, aurea per excellentiam vitœ, aurea per integritatem et puritatem, aurea per plenitudinem gratia`, "Mary is a golden urn for the excellence of her life, for her integrity and purity, and for the fullness of grace" we read in the Homilies of Saint Amadeus, Bishop of Lausanne (12th century).

> 7. Gideon's fleece (VELLUS GEDEONIS).
>    The image appears in the Biblia Pauperum on the Annunciation page, opposite the Nativity page. It is a typological relationship between the Old Testament text of the Book of Judges (6, 37-38), and Mary's virginity: Gideon, the fifth judge of Israel, wants to know if God wants to use him to liberate the Promised Land. In response to Gideon, a miracle occurs. A fleece placed on the ground is covered with dew and the judge collects it in a cup while the earth around it has dried. In the Middle Ages, this dry and pure space was interpreted as a symbol of Mary's virginity. Gideon wins in combat, thanks to this sign from God.

<sub>*Extracted from [contemplataaliis.blogspot.com](https://contemplataaliis.blogspot.com/2017/03/schongauer-y-el-retablo-de-los.html) (Spanish)*</sub>